# Symmetricds : solution synchronization from MySQL Slave DB to SQL Server DB?

Tags: symmetricds

I have 2 node
node master : connect to MySQL Slave
node client : connect to SQL Server

Is there a solution to use symmetricds for synchronization from MySQL Slave DB to SQL Server DB ?

Comment: Yes, there is. Have you tried configuring it?

Comment: @BorisPavlović yep . pls help me :D

Comment: @BorisPavlović i have tried configuring. i have reloaded data ok . but cannot sync . i have researched replication master-slave of mysql . db slave just read data so trigger in slave cannot capture data

Comment: What’s the exception of the error that the agent logs in the console or in the log files?